# Cross reference between 2 sheets of a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yZfvre907zi4VFz4fgQVdL1i8uWZDn7dmG-BWVbQXTQ/edit?usp=sharing) that has 2 sheets, People & Companies:

If a cell in **Column B** of **People** matches the text in a cell of **Column A** in **Companies** then I need the contents of **Column B** in **Companies** added to **Column C** in **People**

**PEOPLE SHEET BEFORE :**

[image: people sheet]

**COMPANY SHEET :**

[image: company sheet]

**PEOPLE SHEET AFTER :**

[image: success]

I've been attempting to use a matching script found elsewhere on Stackoverflow but it's been unsuccessful:

```
 function myFunction(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var people = sheet.getSheetByName("People");
  var companies = sheet.getSheetByName("Companies");

  var people = people.getRange(column(b));
  var data1 = people.getValues();

  var data2 = companies.getValues();

}
```

I'm really stuck, any idea? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need script. Vlookup will do it. Enter this in 'People' C2:

```
=iferror(arrayformula(vlookup(B2:B,Company!A2:B,2,false)),"")
```

Comment: From the script of question, the sheet name may be ``Companies``.

Comment: Thank you Ed and @Tanaike, I tried it in a copy using 'companies', but got no result = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KLnoB5OhfvEY9cdrOBby5zKfi09a1mVE0NgqEzDCP1c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ed Nelson, thank you that worked perfectly - you are a gentleman

Answer (score 1):

Although Vlookup will do it for you, this is one way to do it by script if you're still curious.

```js
function myFunction(){
  var peopleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PEOPLE");
  var companySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("COMPANIES");

  // --------- SPECIFY INFO --------------
  var ignoreTitles = true; // If you have titles, this will offset them.

  var peopleColumn = 2; // Which column to use in the People sheet to check comparison
  var companyColumn = 1; // Which column to use in the Company sheet to check comparison

  var companyColumnToGet = 2; // Which column in Company sheet to transfer data from
  var peopleColumnToSet = 3; // Which column in People sheet to transfer data into
  // -------------------------------------

  var start = 1;
  if(ignoreTitles) {
    start++;
  }

  for(var i=start; i<=peopleSheet.getDataRange().getValues().length; i++) {
    for(var j=start; j<=companySheet.getDataRange().getValues().length; j++) {
      if(peopleSheet.getRange(i,peopleColumn).getValue() === companySheet.getRange(j,companyColumn).getValue()) {
        peopleSheet.getRange(i,peopleColumnToSet).setValue(companySheet.getRange(j,companyColumnToGet).getValue());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kenji  :3